# How to calculate age from birthday when creating a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is my code

```
CREATE TABLE patients (
    PatientID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    PatientBirthday date,
    PatientAge int AS (year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - year(PatientBirthday))

);
```

But whenever I run it I get a syntax error highlighting on AS

Comment: im using access

Comment: Refrain from calculated fields. Queries are for that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.  The expressions that are available in a calculated field are limited.  If you remove the line with the calculated field, create the table, then shift it into design view and try to add the calculated field manually, you'll get the design interface and it will give you a list of the available functions.  YEAR is listed, but NOW isn't,

[image]

and I think NOW is the Access equivalent of the ANSI current_timestamp.  If you attempt YEAR(now()) you will see this:

[image]

YEAR([PatientBirthday]) is accepted by the editor, so that's not the issue.  Sorry, I think this is not possible, at least not the way you want to do it.  I think you will have to calculate during the SELECT or UPDATE the ages after insert, or you could hardcode the current year: 2021 - YEAR([PatientBirthday]).  I know that's less than ideal.  It would also be possible to store the current year in a separate table and update that with VBA at database startup, then use that field in the calculation.

Access can be very hacky at times.  I really would suggest using a full featured ANSI compliant DBMS if you have the choice.